# useEffect cleaning function is not called when tab is closed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this useEffect which I use just for cleaning:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return function cleanup() {
      if (!room || !currentPortal) return;
      leavePortal(
        room,
        currentPortal,
        currentUserProfile && currentUserProfile.uid
          ? currentUserProfile.uid
          : uniqueId
      );
      detachListener();
    };
  }, [isFirstLoad, currentUserProfile, currentPortal]);
```

I can go back and forth and it works just fine, but does nothing if the tab is closed. Is that how useEffect works? Does it not detect the tab closing?

Comment: I don't think useEffect() triggers on page unload. You'll have to explicitly add a `beforeunload` listener for that.

Comment: You should use the [beforeUnload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) for that. Also remove the event listener when component unmounts.

Comment: @HMR you mean the listener for beforeUnload? But isn't that the last thing that happens? Do I remove it from within itself? Also, does it actually remains after the tab closes? I would have thought that once the tab closes everything wipes

Comment: @Tsabary The effect in your question will run when component unmounts, it might cause an error when you run it again when window unloads. If it doesn't then you can leave it there but if you keep mounting and unmounting the component then you will add a lot of listeners and may get unexpected results when the window is closed (unload of the window will trigger all the event listeners). See given answer, that will work.

Comment: Your hook seems to have a lot of missing dependencies like room, leavePortal, uniqueId and dispatchListener. If these are all imported and are not created within your component then you're fine but if any of them are not you might end up with a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/#31-useeffect). Your linter should have warned you about it since recent create-react-app projects use [exhaustive deps](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`useEffect` will not detect tab close by default.

However you can implement that by yourself:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const cleanup = () => {
    // do your cleanup
  }

  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', cleanup);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', cleanup);
  }
}, []);
```